# Y-Axis Units on pnorm command?

Tags: stata

When one generates a graph using the `pnorm` command it generates a graph with units:

- Y Axis: `Normal F[(Variable Name-m)/s]`
- X Axis: `P[i] = i/(N+1)`

The X-Axis seems reasonable to calculate by hand. I am confused as to what the units of the Y-Axis mean?

How does Normal `Normal F[(Variable Name-m)/s]` break down? Does `m` represent the mean and `s` represent the standard deviation. If so, what does the function `Normal F()` represent?

Comment: Note that commands and functions are disjoint in Stata. The terms are not synonyms. (Edited to correct this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a query about the underlying statistics.

F (usually better as *F*) is standard statistical notation for the cumulative distribution function, often abbreviated distribution function. That's the probability of being less than any particular value. For a single variable, as here, the function approaches 0 as values decrease towards the minimum of that variable (nothing can be less than the minimum) and 1 as values increase towards its maximum  (nothing can be more).

In the case of the normal (Gaussian) distribution in principle any finite value is possible. The distribution function depends on the mean `m` and standard deviation `s`, as you surmise, which specify the particular normal distribution being compared with data. So, in words we have "normal distribution function with mean and standard deviation for these data".

All documented:

[Stata manual entry for pnorm](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/rdiagnosticplots.pdf)

[Wikpedia on normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)

[Wikipedia on P-P plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%93P_plot)

[FAQ on plotting positions](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/percentile-ranks-and-plotting-positions/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If we were to convert this into an Excel formula, which function would we use for the normal distribution part?

Comment: If you're asking for the name of an Excel function, I would have to look it up.